# Splash Screen Like Google

Tags: android, splash-screen, app-startup

I want to create splash screen like google splash screen(image attached below) using layer-list.I tried but UI behaving different on different devices.
here is my code

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:opacity="opaque">
    <!-- The background color, preferably the same as your normal theme -->
    <item android:id="@+id/item_bottom_stroke" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- Your product logo - 144dp color version of your app icon -->
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/web_hi_res_512" />
    </item>
    <item android:gravity="bottom">
        <bitmap android:gravity="bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/launcher_text2" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Is there any way that UI look like google apps on different devices ?

[material design reference](https://material.google.com/patterns/launch-screens.html#launch-screens-branded-launch)

[image]

Comment: Checked it in Emulator and it is working fine. Can you post screenshot of your issue?

Comment: getting issue when check on different devices. text not showing on some devices.

Comment: You mean "launcher_text2" image, rt? Append this image with Space padding in bottom of about height of (Bottom toolbar + margin you want)

Answer (score 0):

You mean "launcher_text2" image, rt? Append this image with Space padding in bottom of about height of (Bottom toolbar + margin you want)

[image: Something like this] and check it again